# docker logging container not reading docker logs

Tags: docker, syslog, containers

new to docker....

so got a few containers running and i want to run a logging container to collect all the logs up and send them to Rapid7.

the rapid7 container is working as its sending stats to the remote syslog.

BUT... it is not sending container logs...

using the hello-world container to create a test container log as its simple.

```
docker run hello-world
```

then look at the logs:

```
docker logs compassionate_chaum

Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
 1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
 2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
    (amd64)
 3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
    executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
 4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
    to your terminal.

To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
 $ docker run -it ubuntu bash

Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
 https://hub.docker.com/
```

shows the standard output, great.
but it doesn't appear on my remote log?

what am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working fine. This is the standard output log of `hello-world` docker image.

Comment: Hi @Raj Srujan Jalem, apologies, but im not sure you have interpreted my question entirely correctly. my problem is that, the logging docker container should be shipping these logs to a remote syslog server, using the output from the other containers.